# Preserve newlines when parsing xml

Tags: android, xml, newline, sax

I'm using the SAX xml parser to parse some xml data which contains newlines. When using Attributes#getValue, the newline data is lost. How can keep the newlines?

Comment: Typical, after spending ages searching, I find the answer after posting this question. Solution was to use &#xA; instead of \n

Comment: Can you describe a bit more? I am stucked and cant find much help. Thanks

Comment: Replace instances of \n with &#xA when exporting to xml.

Comment: Replace inside  public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) ?? but char[] is already tempered after newLine  , can you please elaborate your words ???

Comment: You should post it as an answer and accept your own solution.  That way people won't think this question still needs answering.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution was to use `&#xA;` instead of \n

Comment: Please mention how you solved it in this answer, where it belongs :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code when getting the String to parse:

```
  public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) { 


      for(int i=start; i<length; i++)
      if(!Character.isISOControl(ch[i]))
          content.append(ch[i]);

  }
```